# Ruby variables in scripts

Tags: ruby, regex, string

This seems to work correctly and display the results I want

```
Dir["/Users/ondrovic/RubyTest/**/*.txt"].each do |i|
    puts i.green if File.readlines(i).grep(/test/).any?
end
```

Why when I try like this does it not populate info

```
print "Enter search dir"
src = gets
print "Enter search term"
trm = gets

puts "Looking in #{src} for #{trm}"

Dir["#{src}/**/*.txt"].each do |i|
    puts i.green if File.readlines(i).grep(/"#{trm}"/).any?
end
```

I have also tried it this way

```
Dir[src + "/**/*.txt"].each do |i|
   puts i.green if File.readlines(i).grep(/ + trm + /).any?
end
```

Working code

```
require 'colorize'
print "Enter search dir\n".green
src = gets.chomp
print "Enter search term\n".blue
trm = gets.chomp

puts "Looking in #{src} for #{trm}"

Dir["#{src}/**/*.txt"].each do |i|
    puts i.green if File.readlines(i).grep(/#{trm}/).any?
end
```

Comment: replace `/"#{trm}"/` with `/#{trm}/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of the [`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) includes trailing newline:

```
>> gets
asdf
=> "asdf\n"  # <----
>>
```

Remove it using [`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chomp):

```
print "Enter search dir"
src = gets.chomp
print "Enter search term"
trm = gets.chomp
...
```

---

In addition to that, the pattern `/"#{trm}"/` includes `"`. Remove them:

```
/#{trm}/
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Regexp::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-new):

```
Regexp.new(trm)
```